# Designing widths and heights of Android widgets

Tags: android, xml, android-widget

What is the best way to design the width and height of your widgets so it looks nice in both portrait and landscape mode? For example, I'm trying to make a simple sign up page, and when they enter their information and it's in the correct format, I want to display a little checkbox image right next to the corresponding `EditText` view.

My particular problem is that without the image checkboxes, I can just set the `EditText` width to `match_parent` and it will extend to the entire screen in both portrait and landscape mode. But once I add the `ImageView` checkbox next to the `EditText` widget, I have to set `EditText`'s width to a specific dp value to give room for the checkbox to be displayed. But now that is has a specific dp value, when I rotate the screen to landscape mode, the `EditText` view has a much shorter width than I want.

So my question is, what is the best way to design the height and width of widgets so they look good with nearly all phones and look good in both portrait and landscape mode? Am I just supposed to design a separate layout for landscape mode all the time, or is there a smarter way to avoid that?

Comment: I don't think Android widget is the word you are looking for: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html

Comment: In Android Studio, EditText and ImageView (the one's I mentioned) are under the widget category. That includes buttons, progress bars, etc. So I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
     <!-- your stuff here --> />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    <!-- your stuff here --> />
 />
```

Comment: Oh, so `layout_weight` is key to solving this then? Cool, I didn't know that.